# Filter on data passed into directive throws exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I am using a directive to template a list of objects. Depending on where the directive is used, the list of objects being rendered in the template should be filtered. In one approach, the code looks like the following:

*person_list.html*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in (people | selected:true)">
  <a class="selected-{{ person.selected }}" ng-click="toggleSelect( person )">{{ person.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*person_list.js*

```
app.directive('personList', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {people: '=list'},
    controller: "ListCtrl",
    templateUrl: 'person_list.html'
  }
});
```

*selected_filter.js*

```
app.filter('selected', function(){
  return function(list, criteria){
    return list.filter(function(element){
      return !!element.selected === criteria;
    });
  }
});
```

And the directive is being used as follows:

`<person-list list="people"></person-list>`

Another approach which I would like to use is to filter the list from outside of the directive:

*person_list.html*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people">
  <a class="selected-{{ person.selected }}" ng-click="toggleSelect( person )">{{ person.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the directive would be used as follows:

`<person-list list="people | selected:true"></person-list>`

However, Angular does not like this. The exception `Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined` is thrown inside the filter. A goal is to keep the directive as simple as possible, partly by having this filter be an optional component.

What I would like to know is:

1. Why does the first approach work while the second does not?
2. What alternative approaches would satisfy these requirements?

See the [full Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vR2CbfEqxgOewa6RZct4?p=preview).

Comment: simpler demo would help... so don't have to wade through multiple files

Comment: I updated the Plunker to use only the relevant components. Please have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few race conditions (order of initialisations) and other subtleties in the code as it currently stands.

First, to solve the error you described.

#### What is the initial value of a `promise` before resolution

When `people | selected:true` is evaluated for the first time, `people` is an unresolved promise. Hence, `angular` calls the filter with the value `undefined`. This is the correct (TM) behaviour because there will be filters which will want to catch that `undefined` and then display some default value while the value is being resolved in the background. This case needs to be handled in the filter:

```js
app.filter('selected', function(){
  return function(list, criteria){
    if (typeof list !== 'undefined') {
      return list.filter(function(element){
        return !!element.selected === criteria;
      });
    } else { 
      return []; 
    }
  }
});
```

This filter can be more easily written as `people | filter:{'selected' : true}` using angular's `filter` [which handles promises (and everything else) gracefully](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L109). I am assuming you have your reasons for using custom filters.

### Other issues

#### Is the directive `scope` initialised first or the controller's `scope`

The property `people` is defined both on `ListCtrl` and on the `directive`'s isolated scope:

```js
app.directive('personList', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {people: '=list'},  // <-- 'people' on scope
    controller: "ListCtrl",    // <-- Also defines 'people' on scope
    templateUrl: 'person_list.html'
  }
});
```

It is unclear which `people` will actually carry over to the template. I suspect that you need the `toggleSelection` function from the controller but not the initialisation of the `people` field. Hence, you want something of the kind:

```js
app.directive('personList', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {people: '=list'},
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
        $scope.toggleSelect = function (p) { 
            p.selected = !p.selected; 
        };
    }],
    templateUrl: 'person_list.html'
  }
});
```

Depending on how you want to communicate with the rest of the application, you can you can define the `toggleSelect` function in the `link` function or the `controller` (as shown here).

### On mixing filters and promises

With these changes too, you will run into `Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` because of the `=list` binding on the directive and the `people | selected:true` returning new list objects. I suspect the issue is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1397), since only object equality and not `angular.equals` is being used. However, I am not an expert there.

I do not like using `filters` on anything other than primitives because it becomes difficult to ensure object equality and preventing such errors. Also, I am not a big fan of using `promises` directly in the UI because of exactly these problems.

As a rule, I find it better to let the `controller` do the task of filtering and any other logic sitting between the UI `model` and the `view`. Hence, I would define a property on the `$scope` in the controller which is set after the `promise` has been resolved and then use that in the template. This does make the controller a bit thicker.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8eMvGUWsxQwe4fhypBf1?p=preview

Comment: if you use `angular.isUndefined` avoids the digest problems and promise issues. See demo I provided. I was playing with same you did using $watch but got it to work without it

Comment: One of the interesting problem was using using a `filter` expression in a two way binding in a directive. The suggestions you make in your answer are sensible but you have worked around the issue by recommending using the filtering on `ng-repeat`. How this example works in the end is largely immaterial. :-)

Comment: still have to work within the limitations of passing references to objects or variables into directives via their attributes. There is quite a bit of code used to make `ng-repeat` work in source

Comment: BTW- one very helpful solution is to use `resolve` to make ajax calls within `routeProvider` to make sure data is available before the view template is digested.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I had not thought of that. However, using promises still complicates sharing of the models across the application a lot. I suspect how they make it work in `ng-repeat` is by using `$watchCollection` and then manually keeping track of what has changed instead of just using `$watch`.

Comment: `resolve` is worth looking at... cool how you pass data to controllers also using dependency injection. Here's some handy video links  http://egghead.io/search?q=resolve

Answer (score 1):

Numerous problems in your set up. Suggest you use a completely different controller reference in your directive, as you are passing data to directive from `ListCtrl`, then calling that same controller inside the directive and retrieving same data again

One problem is digest cycle will run the directive before the data is available from the promise. Promises don't seem to pass to directives. This means the scope of `people` in directive isn't defined when filter is first run

To fix the filter:

```
app.filter('selected', function(){
  return function(list, criteria){
     if(!angular.isUndefined(list)){
        return list.filter(function(element){
          return !!element.selected === criteria;
        });
     }
  }
});
```

Don't try filtering on an attribute of a directive. `ng-repeat` allows doing it because it;s directive expects filters. Put your filter on the ng-repeat in your template, or filter the data inside directive itself.

[Here's a version of your plunker that doesn't throw errors](http://plnkr.co/edit/u8lUqZNhRo85u3dWRlAT?p=preview)